# Can "Dark Strings" give rise to "Dark Matter"?

Tags: string-theory, dark-matter, dark-energy

If dark matter consists of some kind of particles that can be described by String Theory, could we be able to describe this kind of strings ("dark strings", i.e, the strings which give rises to dark matter) mathematically? Or how to begin to deal with this subject theoretically?

Comment: Superpartners are described by superstrings in the exact same way regular particles are, so I'm not quite sure what the question is.

Comment: Voting to reopen as the question can be answered by a description of the kind of string states that supply the dark matter, in existing string models.

Comment: Since this question has not been reopened... As with particle theory, there are many approaches to dark matter in string theory. It can be just another string state from the sector that also describes visible matter. It can be something from another braneworld entirely. And there are other known possibilities too.